# Assumption for separate continuity implies joint continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I think the following is true and was hoping someone could help me think up a proof or (hopefully not) a counterexample.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff. If $f :X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is separately continuous then $f$ is jointly continuous.

Comment: Does anyone know under what additional conditions on $f$, $X,\,Y,\,Z$ does the statement hold? I would be happy with $X$ and $Y$ being cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $Z=\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f$ being separately analytic (even $m=1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately,

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\qquad 0 &, x = y = 0\\ \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &, x^2+y^2 > 0\end{cases}$$

is separately continuous on $[-1,1]^2$.